# Vue JS - Adding dynamic number to images (in between image name and image format)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have bind image with the image tag like this

```
<img  title="head" :src="availableParts.heads[selectNextHeadIndex].src"/>
```

added called this from json

```
 {
      id: 1,
      description:
        'A robot head with an unusually large eye and teloscpic neck -- excellent for exploring high spaces.',
      title: 'Large Cyclops',
      src: images('./head-big-eye.png'),
      type: 'heads',
      cost: 1225.5,
    },
```

but image is displaying as shown in screenshot. but it automatically adds some number to image name and image format.
How I can remove the numbers?and make it simple like this `head-big-eye.png`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable hashing in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  filenameHashing: false,
}
```

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing